# Backup postgreSQL database in Linux and restore in Windows

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-backups

I am trying to dump a postgres database in Linux and then restore it in Windows. However, when I use the following command:

```
pg_dump -F p tempDB > tempDB.dump.out
```

The created file will not be usable in Windows. In fact, when I log into Windows I cannot see the file there! Then when I log in in Linux I notice the tempDB.dump.out file does not exist there either anymore. This is however, when I use the above command, tempDB.dump.out has a size about 400MB.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: *when I log into Windows I cannot see the file there*... where is *there*? Where are you putting the file?

Comment: Windows doesn't have access to where I initially save the backup file. Therefore, I copy the file in a folder that is accessible in Windows. However, when I log into Windows the folder where I copied the file is empty!
Then when I log into Linux the folder is also empty there!

Comment: That's a file system or file system sharing issue, not a database issue. Is this a Linux `/tmp` folder? Are you using samba then for file shares? What if you create any other file in that share (like a simple txt file), can you see it in Windows?

Comment: Once you have your file-sharing problems sorted, use `-Fc` for the custom format. It's quicker to restore and more flexible.

Comment: I could finally resolve this issue. The issue was caused by a software I had installed on Linux. Can anyone give me a hint for restoring the dataset in postgreSQL in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this command **pg_dump -F p tempDB > tempDB.dump.out** the output file will be created in the same directory where you are.  When you copy to some place (other directory) that can be acces for windows, you cant use pg_restore or with the pgadmin programm.